# How to get TypeScript to allow optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

The below code works as intended in JavaScript, but when compiling it to TypeScript I get the error

```
t.ts:11:34 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 6.    
11 console.log(where_undefined(obj, 0, 'category1', 'nested', 'b', 2))
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

t.ts:14:34 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 6.
14 console.log(where_undefined(obj, 0, 'category1', 'nested', 'b', 4))
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Question**

How can I get this function to work in TypeScript?

```js
var obj = [{
  "category1": {
    nested: {
      a: 'string',
      b: [69, 13, 15]
    }
  },
  "category2": "2",
}];

console.log(where_undefined(obj, 0, 'category1', 'nested', 'b', 2))
// print 15

console.log(where_undefined(obj, 0, 'category1', 'nested', 'b', 4))
// print undefined at key 4

function where_undefined(obj) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  args.shift();
  while (args.length) {
    var arg = args.shift();
    if (obj[arg] === undefined) {
      console.log("undefined at key " + arg);
      break;
    } else {
      obj = obj[arg];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `function where_undefined(obj, ...args) { ... }` (with the proper type annotations for obj and args)?

Comment: @A_A This code snippet is from their [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748803/how-to-tell-where-an-object-value-is-undefined).

Comment: @A_A if you know how to implement that, then would mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, like @A_A has described, we should be using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function where_undefined(obj: any, ...args: PropertyKey[]) {
```

We also need to give them types. I have used `any` for `obj` here, because if we had used `unknown`, we'd get many more unnecessary errors in the function body. `PropertyKey` is a built-in type that represents all possible types for keys (`string | number | symbol`).

Since we're using rest parameters, we don't need this bit:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
args.shift();
```

All this is doing is getting the same result as `args` in our new code.

The next change is here:

```
const arg = args.shift()!;
```

We use `!` to assert that this cannot be undefined (since undefined cannot be used as a key). If we did not use an assertion here, we'd get errors when we try to use `arg` as a key:

```
obj[arg] // ! Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.
```

However, now when you give it an object, it always returns `any`, no matter what the type of the object was, so we'll go back and change `any` to use a generic:

```
function where_undefined<T>(obj: T, ...args: PropertyKey[]): T {
```

But with this change, we get even *more* errors in the body. We can "ignore" these by changing this to an external signature:

```
function where_undefined<T>(obj: T, ...args: PropertyKey[]): T {
function where_undefined(obj: any, ...args: PropertyKey[]) {
```

The final result can be seen in this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WP9Azw).